# How to test logstash with PHP script

Tags: php, testing, logstash

I just have installed logstash, configured its config file with input, filter and output and finally have run it. Is it possible to test if logstash pushes log data by writing some PHP script? Can someone provide me some php script that can catch log data, sending from logstash?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following to get the list of logs in your elasticsearch index :

```
    $date = date("Y.m.d");
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $port = "9200";
    $index = "logstash-".$date;
    $type = "*";


    $log = array();
    $query = '{"query":{"match_all":{}}}';

    $curl = curl_init();
    if ($curl) {
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $host."/".$index."/".$type."/_search");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl)) {
            echo curl_error($curl); //error
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        if (!$result) {
        //error
        }
        $arr=(json_decode($result, true));
    $logs = $arr['hits']['hits'];
        // If any logs were found
        if (count($logs)>0) {
    foreach ($logs as $q) {
             // load the data in the $data array
            $log[] = $q["_source"];
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($log);
            echo "</pre>";
    }
        }
    }
?>
```

Cheers.

Comment: I just tried your code and nothing happened. I think that there is no connection between the php code and elasticsearch. Now I am trying to just get True when connection is established successfully. Any advise how to?

Comment: is your code for catching logs from logstash or from elasticsearch?

Comment: The code I provided will check your elasticsearch server (since I saw in the comments that you are using elasticsearch as an output method ) and see if there are any logs indexed from logstash, you might want to change your $host, $port, and $index based on your configuration

Comment: Please check that you have the CURL extention loaded and that your elasticsearch server is running, I hope this will help.
P.S: the code is running well for me

Answer (score 0):

Do you have use [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/) to store the log data? After you have store the logs in elasticsearch, you can use restful api to get the logs by php.

Comment: yes I did. Could you please provide me some PHP example with  restful api? I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Well. I think there are tons of example at google. Try this: http://support.qualityunit.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP

Answer (score 0):

You must install [Elasticsearch PHP client](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html) to communicate with elasticsearch server.